# How do I trigger a forced update with react-i18next?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am loading some resource bundles asynchronously, and I want to refresh the entire app when it's loaded. How can I do this?

```
i18n.addResourceBundle(locale, ns, messages, true, true);

// app is not updated
```

---

**Update:** I can use the [`bindToStore: 'add'`](https://react.i18next.com/latest/i18next-instance) option, but since multiple bundles can be loaded, I'd like to prevent the refresh until *after* everything is loaded.

So, for now, calling `i18n.changeLanguage(lang);` and `bindToStore` seems to be the only options,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call [`i18n.changeLanguage(lang);`](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#changelanguage) it will trigger re-render of the app.

Comment: Yes, I guess I could do this, but since loading these bundles already happen inside the `languageChanged` event handler, I was hoping for a more direct approach.

Comment: I don't see any other way to trigger re-render, https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/blob/f7bc9f7010d8a5b217047450c394c6e137790349/react-i18next.js#L886